# Xamarin Forms binding to a custom cell without hardcoded property names

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a working listview which binds to a custom cell. However, I wonder if I really have to have a model with the property named just like the custom cell properties.

My custom viewcell (lots of stuff left out):

```
public class RecordListCell : ViewCell
{
        public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty = BindableProperty.Create ("Heading", typeof (string), typeof (RecordListCell), null);

        public string Heading {
            get { return (string)GetValue (HeadingProperty); }
            set { SetValue (HeadingProperty, value); }
        }
        protected Label headingLbl { get; set; }

        public RecordListCell ()
        {
            headingLbl = new Label () ;
            headingLbl.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Heading"));

            // from here on I construct a stacklayout and insert the label above
    }
}
```

My page (lots of stuff left out)

```
public TopicsPage ()
{
    _topicList = new ListView ();
    var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof (RecordListCell));
    // NOT WORKING
    // cell.SetBinding (RecordListCell.HeadingProperty, "Name");

    // working (I must name the property exactly like the property in my custom cell)
    cell.SetBinding (RecordListCell.HeadingProperty, "Heading");
    _topicList.ItemTemplate = cell;

    _topicList.ItemsSource = MyRepo.GetTopics();
}
```

So the above works, but I am forced to have MyRepo.GetTopics() to return a list of objects that have a property named Heading. I would like to reuse this custom cell with any kind of object lists and just specifying the binding on the page like my comment shows, but that's no worky.

Am I expecting the wrong thing here or is my approach wrong?

Comment: Are you expecting the heading's to be constant for the same page? or are you expecting the heading's content to be dynamic by the item's content?

Comment: Constant for the same page, but many pages will want to use the same custom cell so I don't want the cell to require naming of the model properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way binding is set for label is "Header" from bindingcontext, where you don't have a property called "Header" in the GetTopics(), so you have set the source of binding for the label as RecordCell.

```
headingLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
                    new Binding("Heading",BindingMode.Default, null, null, null, source: this));
```

Now

```
cell.SetBinding (RecordListCell.HeadingProperty, "Name");
```

this code should work, hope that helps !

Comment: Those additional parameters are all defaulted anyway, right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct those are defaulted by the last parameter i.e. Source:null is the default value instead of that i've assigned the parent RecordListCell which makes it to look for Heading property.

Answer (score 0):

ListView item's BindingContext is tied to the item's model. You have to figure another way to insert that data into the view cell & data template.

You can change the custom view cell constructor to accept the (per page) heading value

`MyCustomCell(string perPageHeadingText)`

And assign that as the heading value (since it's going to be unique per page), the rest of the viewcell content can be binded to the item source as usual.

You would then use the the different DataTemplate constructor to create the template:

`var myTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => { return new MyCustomCell("MyPageTitle"); });`

Comment: My bad. I meant that the name of the property is unique per the page, not the value. Anyway, Dinesh answer solved it for me. Thanks anyway.